# Infimum, supremum of a set problems

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

I am solving some infimum/supremum problems, and my book has different answers for some of the problems.

Let $A = \{ x \in \Bbb N | x^2 < 5\}$ find sup A and inf A, their answer is sup A = $\sqrt5$, inf A = $-\sqrt5$.

I think this is wrong, since A is a finite set, its clear sup A = 2 and inf A = 0, am i missing something?

Another one, $A = \{x^2+x |x \in (-1, 1)\}$ they say sup A = 1 and inf A = 0, i think sup A = 2 and inf A = 0, again am i wrong?

Comment: You seem to have the right answers to the questions as phrased.  Something weird going on there.

Comment: Its very annoying when you cant even rely on the solutions in the book, good this website exists!

Comment: I imagine the first is just a typo and they meant $x\in\mathbb{R}$.

For part two notice that say $x=-1/2$ in your equation gives $-1/4$ and so your infimum is off.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the first, I'd say you're right. The official solution woul be for $x \in \mathbb{Q}$ (or $\mathbb{R}$) instead of $x \in \mathbb{N}$.

For the second one, take $x = -\frac{1}{2} \in (-1,1)$ (I assume these are the real numberse between $-1$ and $1$, excluding the borders). Then
$$x^2 + x = \frac{1}{4} - \frac{1}{2} = -\frac{1}{4},$$
so $\inf A \le -\frac{1}{4}$.

Hint to solve this:

> You want to check the borders of the interval (-1,1) and any minimum/maximum of your expression in that interval, for which derivations will be very helpful. One of the obtained *x* (should be 3 of them) will give you the infimum.

Comment: i tried like this, -1 < x < 1 and  0 <= x^2 < 1 adding them up gives -1 < x^2 + x < 2, so inf A = -1 not sure if it is correct

Comment: No, it is not. Take $x + (-x)$ on the same interval. Your approach will give you infimum $-2$ and supremum $2$, which is obviously wrong. Do you know how to find min/max of a function (i.e., using derivations)? If so, see my hint (go over the gray arrea with your mouse and the text will appear).

Comment: To elaborate: the problem with your approach is that minimums of the two expressions don't happen for the same $x$, so summing them will generally not give you the right minimum (or, in this case, infimum, but it's the same argument).

Comment: yes i do but i am not supposed to use it on this problem, it would be too easy, i am looking for a different solution...

Comment: Ok, then solve $x^2+x = 0$. The minimum is $(x_1+x_2)/2$, where $x_1,x_2$ are the nul-points of the function.

Comment: god it was so simple, didn't even think about this, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct with the first one (inf $0\in\mathbb N$). The answer in the book would be correct if the problem statement had $\mathbb R$ or $\mathbb Q$ instead of $\mathbb N$.

For the second note that $x^2+x=(x+\frac12)^2-\frac14\ge-\frac14$ with equality when $x=-\frac12$, so $\inf A=-\frac14$; and from the same formula you can see that $x^2+x<(1+\frac12)^2-\frac14=2$.

Comment: Hmmm. I think that's pretty much what the other (first) answer stated.